# mysql sub query count returning gloabl count and ignoring where

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

At the moment "matrix_mct_versions" is a table with 73 entries. When I run this query the "version_count" always returns 73, ie the full number of rows. When I run the sub select query on its own i get the real count as per the com_ID param sent. I cannot see what I am doing wrong with this.. can anyone help?

```
SELECT
    a_ID as com_ID,
    option_number,
    comment,
    word_count,
    gender,
    sample,
    (
        SELECT
            count(a_ID)
        FROM
            matrix_mct_versions
        WHERE
            com_ID = com_ID
    ) as version_count
FROM
    matrix_mct
WHERE
    attribute_number = :attribute_number AND
    grade_number     = :grade_number AND
    attribute_type   = :attribute_type
ORDER BY
    option_number
```

Returns results like this:

```
[0] => Array
                (
                    [com_ID] => 678
                    [option_number] => 1
                    [comment] => TODO primary function missing for controller y
                    [word_count] => 7
                    [gender] => 2
                    [sample] => 0
                    [version_count] => 73
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [com_ID] => 679
                    [option_number] => 2
                    [comment] => TODO make this green
                    [word_count] => 4
                    [gender] => 2
                    [sample] => 0
                    [version_count] => 73
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [com_ID] => 680
                    [option_number] => 3
                    [comment] => TODO make this better
                    [word_count] => 4
                    [gender] => 2
                    [sample] => 0
                    [version_count] => 73
                )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one problem is your subquery.  It is not correlated.  I think you mean:

```
(SELECT count(a_ID)
 FROM matrix_mct_versions
 WHERE matrix_mct_versions.com_ID = matrix_mct.com_ID
) as version_count
```

Comment: ahhh.. i thought that if i declared 'a_ID as com_ID,'  that com_ID would be like passing a variable down the query for the subquery to use..

Comment: @John . . . There is method to the madness. MySQL explains its scoping rules for subqueries here (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html).